# Escolher qual fragment irá ser mostrado na activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-activity

Tenho uma `Activity` que é solicitado o e-mail e se o e-mail existir mostro uma `Activity` com um `Fragment` para digitação da senha. Caso este e-mail n exista, quero exibir um `Fragment`, nesta mesma `Activity`, para que seja feito um cadastro.

Minha dúvida é: 
Como escolher qual `Fragment` será inflado ? Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Cada fragmento é representado por uma classe e um layout distinto. Não há erro. Você pode pensar como um fragment sendo um pedaço de uma tela que irá sobrepor temporariamente a activity.

Comment: @Mr_Anderson obrigado, eu vou inflá-los, em uma outra activity, neste caso passo para o bundle da activity os parametros e dependendo do que chegar eu faço o setcontentview para o fragment correto , no onCreate da activity em questão?

Comment: voce pode receber um parametro booleano na activity nº2, tipo temCadastro. Faz um if na activity nº2 --- if(temCadastro == true) {digitarSenha();} else {mostraCadastro();}
Dentro do digitarSenha e do moostraCadastro você infla o fragmento, e não o layout xml do fragmento.
Importante notar que eu acho mais eficiente criar uma classe para o fragmento e não meramente trocar o layout.

Comment: O teste lógico se tem cadastro é feito na activity nº2 (o xml dessa activity estará "em branco"). A activity decide qual fragmento lançar com base no teste lógico temCadastro..O fragmento vai "brotar" em cima da activity (o fragmento é constituído de uma classe específica de fragmento+xml). O interessante a se notar é que o fragmento é diferente de um pop-up, conhecido como dialog.

Comment: @Mr_Anderson entendi. Coloque como resposta que marco. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voce pode receber um parâmetro booleano na activity nº2, por exemplo "temCadastro". Faz um if na activity nº2

```
    if(temCadastro == true) {
      digitarSenha();
    } else { mostraCadastro();
    }
```

Dentro do método digitarSenha() e do mostraCadastro() você infla o fragmento, e não o layout xml do fragmento. 
O teste lógico se tem cadastro é feito na activity nº2 (o xml dessa activity estará "em branco"). A activity decide qual fragmento lançar com base no teste lógico temCadastro..O fragmento vai "brotar" em cima da activity (o fragmento é constituído de uma classe específica de fragmento+xml). O interessante a se notar é que o fragmento é diferente de um pop-up, conhecido como dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro é necessário criar uma condição para verificar suas questões

> Caso este email não exista, quero exibir um fragment..

Tente criar um método que retorne um `boolean` com o nome por exemplo `emailExiste ()` Então você faz assim:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
if(emailExiste){        
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentEmailExiste);      
} else {        
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentEmailNaoExiste);  
}    
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: opa valeu! Toda a esta verificação é feita numa activity anterior a esta que tem estes fragments. É possível eu setar o fragment correto, nesta activity que irá subir, passando por exemplo, o email pelo bundle? Sendo assim, o `setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_login_fragment);` deveria ser `alterado para o activity_new_empty_fragment`  .. . compreendeu minha pergunta?